# minLength in jquery autocomplete multiple values plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete pluguin. Configured to use multiple Values.

I set option  **minLength : 2**

minLength option is working only for first autosuggest words, for multiple values its not working.

How do i configure or which method i need to override to fix this issue.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: So... where is your code? It's very difficult to impossible to help you without seeing what you're working with. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The multiple remote demo on the jQuery UI website demonstrates this behavior. You just need to add a custom search function:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: Thanks Chirstian Vargan. I got my exptected answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found Christian's version from 2012 very useful, but here's a reworked version which works in 2016 (jQuery UI 1.12.0):

```
function split(val) {
  return val.split(/\s+/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
}

source: function(request, response) {
  // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
  const term = extractLast(request.term)
  if (term.length < this.options.minLength) {
    return false;
  }
  response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
    data, term));
}
```

The `minLength` option needs just be provided as usual and will then be used inside the `source` function. See demo if more context is needed.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/eirikbirkeland/pen/BLNbzV)